# Do we have $\mathbb{C}[V^*] \cong S(V)$ or $\mathbb{C}[V] \cong S(V)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, representation-theory

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ and $V^*$ its dual vector space. Let $\mathbb{C}[V^*]$ (resp. $\mathbb{C}[V]$) be the coordinate ring of $V^*$ (resp. $V$) and $S(V)$ the symmetric algebra. Do we have $\mathbb{C}[V^*] \cong S(V)$ or $\mathbb{C}[V] \cong S(V)$? Thank you very much.

Comment: The ring of polynomial functions on $V^*$ should include at the very least the linear functions on $V^*$, that is, the elements of $V^{**}$, which we identify with $V$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S(V)$ should be naturally isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[V^*]$ for a functorial reason. Given a morphism from $V$ to $W$, $S:V\mapsto S(V)$ is a covariant functor. At the same time taking dual and coordinate ring are both contravariant functor so their composition is again covariant functor.
As a result, we should expect $S(V)\cong \mathbb{C}[V^*]$.

Comment: This is a bureaucratic excuse, really.  The reason that the functions on a vector space are the elements of the ring $S(V^*)$ is because the latter is a space of functions on $V$, which the elements of $S(V)$ are not!

Comment: Right. That's a better explanation.